# Except @requestMapping what we can write in spring?

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud

Here I don't want to write **@requestMapping** so except that what will write in *spring.xml* file.
I want to know both scenarios like if I am not using @requestmapping both class level and method level what I have to write ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure your SpringMVC there are two ways **XML Config** and **Annotation Config** :

1. **Configuration using XML** (This is the old way, it's not recommended anymore) :

In *spring-mvc-config.xml* : here we mapped `/hello` to `helloWorldController`

```
<beans ...>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
       <property name="mappings">
        <props>
           <prop key="/hello">helloWorldController</prop>
         </props>
       </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="helloWorldController" class="xx.yy.zz.HelloWorldController" />

</beans>
```

`HelloWorldController` should extends from `AbstractController` and implement `handleRequestInternal()` :

public class HelloWorldController extends AbstractController
    {

```
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hello");

        model.addObject("message", "HelloWorld!");

        return model; //will go to hello.jsp
    }
}
```

2. The equivalent of this with **Annotation config** :

```java
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController
{

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    protected ModelAndView hello() throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hello");

        model.addObject("message", "HelloWorld!");

        return model; //will go to hello.jsp
    }
}
```

Comment: Where we have write this xml file In hybris means in which extension ?

Comment: storefront\web\webroot\WEB-INF\config\spring-mvc-config.xml